# override LGB scope rule?

Tags: python-3.x, scope

I am new-ish to Python, while having considerable experience in C and C++.  One of the things that frequently trips me up is wanting to be able to reference a global variable within a function, as in the following:

```
# first_time needs to be referenced within foo, but could also
# be modified by a different function, or from the global scope,
# so I try to define it globally

first_time = True

def foo():
    if (first_time):
        first_time = False

foo()
```

Python gives an error, and I DO understand how I have violated the [LGB Rule](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-python/1565924649/ch04s03.html):

```
if (first_time):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'first_time' referenced before assignment
```

UPDATE: I found a partial solution, but I don't like it:

```
def foo():
    global first_time
    if (first_time):
        first_time = False

first_time = True     
foo()
```

What I don't like about this solution is that I want to initialize it on the same line where it is declared, but Python appears not to allow me to do that.

Also, it does not allow me to do the same thing inside another function:

```
def bar():
    global first_time
    if (first_time):
        first_time = False
```

Is there a way to declare and initialize it outside of a function, so that it can be checked and updated by more than one function?

Comment: `global first_time; first_time = True` but that is ugly. Why bother? Note, however, that such a thing doesn't *create* the variable in the global scope.

Comment: It also does not help if I need to do the same thing in a second function with the same variable, see update above.

Comment: If `foo` changes a global variable then the change is visible inside `bar`, and vice versa. I'm not sure what problem you are seeing. Could you explain?

Comment: I had assumed that defining first_time in two different functions, both with the global keyword, would cause an error.  In fact, it works fine, so this is the solution to the sharing.  Then I have to initialize it outside of both foo and bar, but after they are defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what Python's `global` keyword does.

It does not *declare* a global variable. Instead, it ensures that - in the current code block - the provided identifier is searched in the global scope instead of in the local scope. (The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) fails to explain this distinction)

For example, the following code would work if `global` actually declared a variable in global scope:

```
def bar():
    global foo
    foo = 1

print(foo)
```

But it yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(foo)
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Since `global` does not declare a variable, your two concerns:

- Not being able to initialize the variable at declaration time, and
- Not being able to use `global foo` in multiple methods

are unfounded! As demonstrated by the following code snippet:

```
foo = 5

def bar():
    global foo
    foo += 1

def baz():
    global foo
    foo += 10

bar()
baz()
bar()
print(foo)
```

Which yields `17`, as expected.

**Update**

However, in general, global variables are frowned upon. Depending on the scenario, there might be a better way.

A little known trick in Python is that you can put properties on methods (this is a consequence of the fact that methods are objects):

```
def bar():
    bar.foo += 1
bar.foo = 5

print(bar.foo)
bar()
print(bar.foo)

bar.foo = 1
```

Which outputs `5`, `6`.

That way, `foo` isn't global, it's restricted to the namespace of `bar`, but still accessible globally with `bar.foo`! This is a very nice solution if `foo` inherently belongs with `bar` but needs to be accessible globally.

A simple, but more concrete example of how this could be useful: suppose you have a method `print()` like so:

```
def print(document, printer=None):
    printer = printer or print.printer
    printer.send(document)
    print.jobcount += 1 
print.printer = get_default_printer()
print.jobcount = 0
```

Then you can:

- Print a document to the default printer with `print(doc)`
- Print to a specific printer with `print(doc, printer=some_printer)`
- Set the default printer with `print.printer = some_printer`
- And query the number of printed documents with `print.jobcount`

Just don't actually name your method `print()`, because that's already a built-in method ;-)

This approach is probably best for small things though. If it gets out of hand, I prefer a class to encapsulate these things, even if I just use static methods:

```
class Print:
    printer = get_default_printer()
    jobcount = 0

    def print(document, printer=None):
        printer = printer or Print.printer
        printer.send(document)
        Print.jobcount += 1
```

So you can do `Print.print(doc)` and `Print.jobcount`, etc...

Comment: I guess this is what I'm looking for, and as close to clean and Pythonesque as I'm going to get.  I did misunderstand what 'global' did.  I do like it better that I can declare the global (without that keyword) at the top, define it as a reference to a global in each global where I want to use it.

Comment: Yes, the text and code example are concise and clear.

Comment: @MarkColan I edited my answer to include some alternatives that might be interesting to you :)

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to create a global variable from a local scope, though it is considered somewhat unpythonic to do so:

```
def foo():
    if not 'first_time' in globals():
        globals()['first_time'] = True
    else:
        global first_time
    if (first_time):
        first_time = False
```

`globals()` is a dictionary that contains all global names (it is informative to type `globals()` in the shell). You can write to it. In the case of `foo`:

```
>>> first_time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    first_time
NameError: name 'first_time' is not defined
>>> foo()
>>> first_time
False
```

Comment: It's very helpful to learn about the globals() dictionary, but it does seem unpythonic as you say.  The best solution I have found so far is declaring it to be global in every function that uses it.  Is that Pythonic?  It seems a bit ugly to me.

Comment: Definitely it is more Pythonic to declare a global variable in the global scope. I even hesitated to post my answer (but, as you say, it is good to know about `globals()`). Aesthetics are subjective. Like many things, Python is an acquired taste. If your tastes are attuned to C/C++ then it will take some time to get use to the local flavor. Type `import this` in the Python shell to get some of the flavor.

Comment: I have grown to appreciate Python (over C/C++) for many reasons, with these: 
1) I don't have to do so much housekeeping, especially with memory and pointer management
2) Richness in the language that replaces function/method calls in C/C++
3) Best of all, an incredible range of modules that do all kinds of useful things so that I no longer have to write and support my own runtime libraries.

Comment: Once you get used to Python it is hard to go back to C/C++ . But -- the speed of C is hard to beat. I sometimes prototype algorithms in Python and then write them in a compiled language. It is also possible to mix C and Python (e.g. using `ctypes`) to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: With today's computers, Python is plenty fast enough for my purposes, but it is good that you can write C for Python for speed-critical code.